# Attach Visual Studio Code to docker Container not working

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, remote-server, vscode-devcontainer

I am connected to a remote dev server on VS Code. I installed the dev containers extension in that so that I can use VS code debugging features inside the remote docker container. The docker extension allows me to see the list of running containers and on right click it shows the option "Attach Visual Studio Code" if dev-containers extension is also there. (otherwise that option doesn't show up)

BUT then a pop up comes which tells me to "select the container to attach VS Code". Which shows a progress bar that never completes and the list of containers in that pop-up is empty! I can see that there are containers running. The docker extension can access them in the sidebar. But the dev container extension seems to be unable to access them in the pop-up!

This feature is working for me when running on other dev servers and it was working for me a few days ago on this dev server as well!

How to look at the dev-container extension logs to resolve this issue ?

Comment: So in the remote explorer tab also when I select the containers dropdown option. It is unable to load the targets!